# 2D transformation, c++, rotate/translate/Scale/centering

Tags: c++, graphics, 2d, computer-science, transformation

I have my code working for translate, the only problem is I cannot seem to center it.
I have tried to do 
"translate = translate * center" and that moves it to the upper right corner it seems like. I am not exactly sure what else I can do. I know my matrix functions are working properly, what am I missing here?

```
oid viewContext::calculate() {
std::cout << "calculate" << std::endl;

/*
 * reinitialize these values
 */
translated.clear();
translated[0][0] = 1;
translated[1][1] = 1;
translated[2][2] = 1;

//translated = translated * center;
//if translate is called
if (whichMethod == trans) {
    translated = translated * center;
    translated = translated * S;
    translated = translated * T;
}
```

the if statement in the code above is something I was trying out, I know its un-necessary.

```
matrix viewContext::model_to_device(const matrix& param) {

    std::cout << "model to device" << std::endl;

    //matrix hold_values = param;

    matrix hold_values = translated * param;

    return hold_values;

}
```

my methods that translate, rotate, etc look like this. well are formatted in this sort of way, they call calculate() at the end

```
void viewContext::rotator(double degree) {
std::cout << "Rotate" << std::endl;

double theta = ((degree * M_PI) / 180);
R[0][0] = cos(theta);
R[0][1] = -1 * sin(theta);
R[1][0] = sin(theta);
R[1][1] = cos(theta);
calculate();
```

}

```
    viewContext::viewContext() :
        translated(3, 3), inverted(3, 3), center(3, 3), T(3, 3), S(3, 3), R(3,
                3) {
    //clear matrix just incase it isn't empty
    //Should be empty but this is precautionary
    translated.clear();

    inverted.clear();

    /*
     * Constant values
     * echelon form
     */
    T[0][0] = 1;
    T[1][1] = 1;
    T[2][2] = 1;

    /*
     * Constant values
     * 300 = x, 400 = y to put at origin.
     */
    center[0][0] = 1;
    center[0][2] = width;
    center[1][1] = -1;
    center[1][2] = height;
    center[2][2] = 1;

    /*
     * Constant values
     * Echelon form
     */
    S[0][0] = 1;
    S[1][1] = 1;
    S[2][2] = 1;

    //TODO
//  /*
//   * Constant values
//   * Echelon form
//   */
    translated[0][0] = 1;
    translated[1][1] = 1;
    translated[2][2] = 1;

    /*
     * Constant values
     * Echelon form
     */
    R[0][0] = 1;
    R[0][1] = 0;
    R[1][0] = 0;
    R[1][1] = 1;
    R[2][2] = 1;

    calculate();
}
```

that is a portion of my constructor, where center is implemented.

```
    private:

    /* translation matrix */
    matrix translated;

    /* translation inverse matrix */
    matrix inverted;

    /* to center the image */
    matrix center;

    matrix T;
    matrix S;
    matrix R;

    const int height = 300;
    const int width = 400;
    void calculate();

    int whichMethod;
};
```

case (KEY_U):
    std::cout << "key down pressed" << std::endl;
    tY = tY - 20;
    vContext.translation(tX, tY);
    gc->clear();
    derived->draw(gc, &vContext);
    break;

I am not exactly sure what i could be doing wrong.
I translate using keyboards (up, down arrow keys and what not. left right)
That works perfectly, but since I have the center part implemented, it will move to the top right and then begin to translate. I am not exactly sure what is going wrong.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your question doesn't really give a lot of information about what you are doing, but it looks like matrix-representations of translations and rotations in homogeneous coordinates. Where do you use them and how? OpenGL? Just remember that order matters when using matrices, so you `translated = center * S * T` applies T first, then S and then center if you later calculate `translated * coordinateVector`

Comment: @Anedar sorry my other posts, some people wrote i gave too much information. 
I am on a linux based virtual Machine.
center is my matrix that contains what you see in the code.
T contains the translated coordinates. S includes the scaled coordinates.
Should I put the portions of code with those here as well?
But yes, I center first, then scale, then translate. which i believe is the correct way to implement it. 
is there something I am missing?

Comment: From the code you posted, `center`, `R` and `translated` are matrices. But what are S and T? what do you expect `model_to_device()` to do? You should give all information relevant to your problem - and only those relevant.

Comment: @Anedar each concrete Shape will use the transformation methods of the ViewContext object to convert its local model coordinates into device coordinates.
S and T are also matrices, it shows in the code portion near the bottom.

Comment: @Anedar I replied to your answer, i believe you may be right, i can definitely double check that.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your matrix-multiplication is implemented correctly, then your translated matrix is build as

```
translated = 1 * center * S * T
```

where 1 is your initial identity-matrix.

I further assume from your comments that `param` in `model_to_device()` is a coordinate vector, resulting in

```
hold_values = translated * param
hold_values = center * S * T * param
```

As you might see, the first operator applied to param is actually T, then S, then center. So first you translate the coordinates, then scale them (with scaling center at (0,0) ) and then use your center-matrix which translates them by (width,height) and inverts y. So basically you first translate, then scale, then center.

Comment: translated is initialized to be in rref pretty much, with 1s on the diagonal.
but I think I understand what you mean, So i should really have 
translated = T * S * center
in my calculated() portion?
So I was doing my math backwards pretty much?

Comment: from what i have it says
translated = translated * center;
translated = translated * S;
translated = translated * T;

so doesn't that mean I am multiplying with the center first, then the S, then the T? not vice versa

Comment: You are multiplying the matrices in this order, yes, But you are always multiplying translated from the left and the other matrix from the right. And matrix multiplications are not commutative. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication

Comment: I'm trying what you are saying, honestly almost in every possible situation it could be in but it is not working.

Comment: Start with only a translation, then only a rotation, then both of them, one time as R * T, one time as T * R. Look closely how the transformations are applied and in which order, especially where the center of the rotation is. This should help a lot in order to understand how the transformations are applied. If you have a new transformation, test it first on its own, then add other transformations one after another.